# Concerning Qpython on android

Tags: python

Just downloaded  the IDE of python for andriod. And I downloaded a book for python 3 i.e Haltermanpython
book
But after learning  the  programming language in the book, I found that  some codes or synthax don't run or some are not  accepted by the compiler.
I don't know what to do,  please help

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please be specific and provide relevant code when asking a question. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your question is much too vague. What code was not accepted, and what exactly was the traceback for the error? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: qpython does'nt support much python, I suggest you use an online python ide or some other mobile app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qpython on android is for python 2.7 and not python 3.x. To use Python 3.x, download Qpython3. Hope this helped. Happy coding!

Comment: Oops. The start was truncated... Sorry if it looks rude